# if $A\subseteq B$ are subsets of a group $G$, then $C_G(B)$ is a subgroup of $C_G(A)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

So to prove the claim, I have to show that, $C_G(B)$ is nonempty, and that, for elements $b_1,b_2\in C_G(B)$, that $b_1b_2^{-1}\in C_G(B)$.

So we know that $A,B$ are subset, not necessarily subgroups, but by definition, if an element $x\in A$, then $x\in B$.  Since the centralizers, $C_G(A),C_G(B)$ are subgroups of $G$, both must contain the unit $1_G$.  Therefore, we have that $C_G(B)$ is nonempty.

Now, I think, before I can show that for elements $b_1,b_2\in C_G(B)$, $b_1b_2^{-1}\in C_G(B)$ I need to show that $C_G(B)\subseteq C_G(A)$.  So if an element $b\in C_G(B)$, then by definition of the centralizer, $gbg^{-1}=b$ for all $b\in B$.  This is where I am confused.  I think the argument can be made that, since $a\in B$, then $gag^{-1}=a$ for $a\in B$ and so $b\in C_G(A)$.  That means $C_G(B)\subseteq C_G(A)$.

Finally, for an element $b_1b_2^{-1}$, we have

$$gb_1b_2^{-1}g^{-1}=gb_1g^{-1}b_2^{-1}=b_1b_2^{-1}$$

which means that $b_1b_2^{-1}\in C_G(B)$.  With these two subgroup criteria met, we have that $C_G(B)\le C_G(A)$.

I'm concerned with my argument in the third paragraph.  Is this the correct usage of the subset criterion of $A\subseteq B$?

Comment: "So if an element $b\in C_G(B)$, then by definition of the centralizer, $gbg^{-1}=b$ for all $b\in B$.  This is where I am confused." No wonder you're confused, as the variable $b$ is defined twice, and $g$ is not defined at all. Instead, try "So if an element $b\in C_G(B)$, then by definition of the centralizer, $gbg^{-1}=b$ for all $g\in B$." If it's true for all $g\in B$, then clearly it's also true for all $g\in A$.

Comment: Any element $g \in G$, which commutes with all elements of B, will naturally commute with all elements of A. So, $C_G(B) \subset C_G(A)  $

Comment: And you already know that $C_G(B)$ and $C_G(A) $ are subgroups of $G$. So, once you show inclusion, proving $C_G(B)$ to be a subgroup of $C_G(A)$ is hardly a big deal.

Comment: Okay.  That sounds better.  Thanks for the help!